# Matching two parts of a string in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm having trouble with a regex to sort the following…

```
http://www.example.com/directory/listings/nostell-priory-2/
http://www.example.com/directory/listings/somerton-court-2/
http://www.example.com/directory/listings/shervage-court-2/
```

to look like the following…

```
http://www.example.com/directory/listings/nostell-priory/
http://www.example.com/directory/listings/somerton-court/
http://www.example.com/directory/listings/shervage-court/
```

I simply want to trim the `-2` bit off the url but ONLY if the url contains the word `listings`.

Can anyone help?

Thanks,

James

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like

```
RewriteRule ^directory/listings/(.*)-2/$ http://www.example.com/directory/listings/$1/ [R]
```